# Strikethrough text on checked checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to make a `div` text get a *strikethrough* on checked checkbox but it doesn't work.

I want to strike over `item-title` when `input type="checkbox"` is checked.

This is what i have right now:

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked+div {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="list media-list">
  <ul id="todoList">
    <li class="swipeout"><label class="item-checkbox item-content swipeout-content">
              <input type="checkbox" id="test1" name="checkbox" value="2" />
              <i class="icon icon-checkbox"></i>
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title-row">
                  <div class="item-title" for="test1">Test</div>
                  <div class="item-after">2019</div>
                </div>
                <div class="item-subtitle">Test text</div>
                <div class="item-text">By Test</div>
              </div>
            </label>
      <div class="swipeout-actions-right"><a href="#" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this item?" class="swipeout-delete">Delete</a></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well there is no `strikethrough` class and the label is the parent of the input....

Comment: I edited away that the same time as the other guy, I have Div right there

Comment: No, that won't work as the `div` is not the first sibling ... use general sibling selector `~`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is the immediately sibling selector and the label isn't one. Try `input[type=checkbox]:checked~.item-inner .item-title`:

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked~.item-inner .item-title {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="list media-list">
  <ul id="todoList">
    <li class="swipeout"><label class="item-checkbox item-content swipeout-content">
              <input type="checkbox" id="test1" name="checkbox" value="2" />
              <i class="icon icon-checkbox"></i>
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title-row">
                  <div class="item-title" for="test1">Test</div>
                  <div class="item-after">2019</div>
                </div>
                <div class="item-subtitle">Test text</div>
                <div class="item-text">By Test</div>
              </div>
            </label>
      <div class="swipeout-actions-right"><a href="#" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this item?" class="swipeout-delete">Delete</a></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This selects the checkbox, then the `~` selects the sibling with the class `item-inner`, then selects the descendant with the class `item-title`

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for the help. I cant mark as answered for 9 minutes but thank you so much for your quick answer!